# Scipy optimize.minimize violate constraints during optimization

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am working on a third party software optimization problem using Scipy optimize.minimize with constraints and bounds (using the SLSQP method). Exactly I am giving inputs to a very complex function (can't write it here) that will launch my software and return me one output I need to minimize.

```py
def func_to_minimize(param):
   launch_software(param)

   return software_output() # I retrieve the output after the software finish his computation
```

While working on it, I notice that during the optimization, the algorithm does not always respect the constraints.

However, the software I am trying to optimize cannot be run with certain inputs values (physical law not to be violated), I wrote these equations as constraints in my code. For example the output flow rate can't be greater than the input flow rate.

I would like to know if it is possible to respect these constraints even during the optimization.

Comment: What is your scipy version? And just to check, your initial state always respects the constraints, correct?

Comment: 1.9.1, yes my initial state respects the constraints, it's after many iteration that my software crash with incorrect value.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could try is intercept `param` and check whether it's feasible before sending it to `launch_software`. If it's not feasible then return `np.inf`. I'm not sure that this will work with SLSQP, but give it a go.

One approach, that will work, would be to use [`optimize.differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html). That function examines to see if your constraints are feasible before calculating the objective function; if it's not then your  objective function isn't called. However, `differential_evolution` does ask for orders of magnitude more function evaluations, so if your objective function is expensive then that could be an issue. One amelioration would be vectorisation or parallel computation.